# Installing service-connector is failing without any hint

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

Having cf installed in version: **cf version 6.22.2**+a95e24c-2016-10-27
and following the steps to install the service-connector plugin from this [documentation](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-connector/index.html) with the following command:

```
 cf install-plugin https://swisscom-plugin.scapp.io/linux64/swisscom-plugin
```

I am getting asked to confirm that I want to install this plugin and when I confirm I am getting:

```
FEHLGESCHLAGEN
Plug-in-Installation abgebrochen
```

which translates to 'FAILED - plugin installation cancelled'.

I verified URL, tried it with a downloaded version of the same bin as a local install, I tried to sudo cf install-plugin, I verified that I have an 64bit Ubuntu.

What could be the issue? It's kind of difficult without any hint about the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found the answer on my own. It's probably an issue with the cf tool.
I was asked in German to confirm whether I want to really install the plugin with this question:

```
Möchten Sie das Plug-in https://swisscom-plugin.scapp.io/linux64/swisscom-plugin installieren? (J oder N)
```

So I confirmed by typing J (for German Ja which means Yes). But obviously the only accepted characters still are Y or N.

So I created an issue with Cloudfoundry Cli: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/994

Comment: awesome. Thank you very much for submitting a bug report upstream. Usually the CF developers very quickly fix bugs. I up voted question and answer. Great to see the CF community effort. It would be very difficult to discover this bug, because 99% of Swisscom Cloud people use Linux and Mac boxes with English language.